# How to use Scrollview with KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a new to react native and i wonder how to use scrollView with keyboardAvoid in the following scene.I have searched for some relevant information, but still have no clue.

Following picture may be more intuitive then explain.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuiEl.png)

```
import  React,{useRef,useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TextInput,ScrollView,KeyboardAvoidingView,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem,setSeLectedItem] = useState(null)
  const [userTyping,setUserTyping] = useState(false);

    const selected = (index) => {
    setUserTyping(true)
      setSeLectedItem(index)
    }
  const onBlur=()=>{
    setUserTyping(false)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1}}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scroll} >
                    {
                        ['1', '2', '3', '4','5','6','7'].map((item,index) => (
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>selected(index)} key={item}>
                            <View style={[styles.itemWrapper,selectedItem===index &&styles.selectedItem]}>
                                <Text style={styles.itemText}>TEST {item}</Text>
                                {
                                    (selectedItem===index)&&userTyping&&
                                    <InputFC 
                                        style={styles.itemInput} 
                                        placeholder='NO TEXT' 
                                        placeholderTextColor={'white'} 
                                        autoCapitalize={'none'}
                                        onBlur={onBlur}
                                    />
                                }                           
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        ))
                    }
                </ScrollView>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
}

const InputFC = (props) => {
    const {style,placeholder,placeholderTextColor,autoCapitalize,onBlur} = props
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(inputRef.current) inputRef?.current?.focus()
    })
    
    return (
    <TextInput 
        style={style} 
        ref={inputRef}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        placeholderTextColor={placeholderTextColor} 
        autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    />)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#24292e',
    },
    scroll: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
    },

    itemWrapper:{
        width: '100%',
        paddingLeft:20,
        paddingVertical:20,
        marginBottom: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#6b6965',
        borderRadius:20,
    },
    itemText:{
        fontSize:20,
        fontWeight:'bold',
        color:'white',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        marginBottom:5,
    }
    ,
    itemInput:{
        fontSize:20,
        color:'white',
    },
    selectedItem:{
        borderWidth:3,
        borderColor:'#2188ff'
    }
});
```

Simplified Demo online:

https://snack.expo.dev/@bravo20203/demo-about-scrollview

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work by changing the `flex: 1` to different components and by adding

```js
behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
style={{flex: 1}}
```

to the `KeyboardAvoidingView`. I have also wrapped your content into a `SafeAreaView` so it does not go into the header on iOS.

Since you are dynamically expanding the TextInput on press, which changes its height, I have added a `keyboardVerticalOffset` to the `KeyboardAvoidingView` and made the overflow visible.

The final code is as follows.

```js
import { useEffect, createRef, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useHeaderHeight } from "@react-navigation/elements";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSeLectedItem] = useState(null);
  const [userTyping, setUserTyping] = useState(false);

  const selected = (index) => {
    setUserTyping(true);
    setSeLectedItem(index);
  };
  const onBlur = () => {
    setUserTyping(false);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={Platform.OS === "ios" && { flex: 1 }}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={30}
      >
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
          {["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"].map((item, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => selected(index)} key={item}>
              <View
                style={[
                  styles.itemWrapper,
                  selectedItem === index && styles.selectedItem,
                ]}
              >
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>TEST {item}</Text>
                {selectedItem === index && userTyping && (
                  <InputFC
                    style={styles.itemInput}
                    placeholder="NO TEXT"
                    placeholderTextColor={"white"}
                    autoCapitalize={"none"}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                  />
                )}
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const InputFC = (props) => {
  const { style, placeholder, placeholderTextColor, autoCapitalize, onBlur } =
    props;
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) inputRef?.current?.focus();
  });

  return (
    <TextInput
      style={style}
      ref={inputRef}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      placeholderTextColor={placeholderTextColor}
      autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#24292e",
    flex: 1,
  },
  scroll: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    overflow: "visible",
  },

  itemWrapper: {
    width: "100%",
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingVertical: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#6b6965",
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "white",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  itemInput: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "white",
  },
  selectedItem: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: "#2188ff",
  },
});
```

I have updated [your snack here](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/demo-about-scrollview). Notice that I have tested this on iOS only.

If the keyboard is opened on select, the selected Input is now fully visible.

Comment: Run on iOS well ,but there is an error with  Android. My target platform Android, do you have a corresponding solution? thanks.

Comment: And the error is? ...

Comment: Sorry, it' doesn't throw error, but  entire page turn into empty on android

Comment: @bravolin I have fixed this for Android. Tests on Samsung Galaxy S9 and iphone 12. See my updated answer and snack.

Comment: Everything go well , that is cool you helped me.